# How to convert accented strings to regular strings in Erlang?

Tags: string, unicode, erlang, diacritics

I want to convert some city names with accented characters to normal strings. For example:

```
<<"SosÃºa">>  to  <<"Sosua">>

<<"Luperón">> to <<"Luperon">>
```

Any leads on how to do this?

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but you can probably use it as "inspiration": https://medium.com/grindr-engineering/confusable-character-detection-in-erlang-98aa47abc9ab

Answer (score 4):

1. apply an [Unicode Canonical Decomposition (NFD)](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) to rewrite characters like ó in the two code points o (U+6F) followed by a separated combining acute accent (U+301) with [unicode:characters_to_nfc_binary/1](https://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_nfc_binary-1)
2. with the regexp `\p{Mn}`, replace ([re:replace/4](https://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#replace-4)) all those combining diacritics (non-spacing marks) like U+301 above
3. optional: apply an Unicode Canonical Composition (NFC) to recompose back the remaining and possible code points together

```
String = "Luperón",
{ok, Re} = re:compile("\\p{Mn}", [unicode]),
Output = unicode:characters_to_nfc_binary(
  re:replace(
    unicode:characters_to_nfd_binary(String),
    Re,
    "",
    [global]
  )
),
Output.
```

Equivalent for Elixir, for reference and information (as it is also based on Erlang's unicode module):

```
string = "Luperón"
output = 
  Regex.replace(~R<\p{Mn}>u, string |> :unicode.characters_to_nfd_binary(), "")
  |> :unicode.characters_to_nfc_binary()
```

Comment: I don't understand the reason for adding an example of Elixir code in your answer when question is Erlang specific? Many languages are using Erlang and its Modules underneath so that doesn't sound like a reason to me. Secondly `:unicode` is not based on Erlang, it actually is a Erlang Module.

Comment: Whoops!!! Got it from Answer Edit History, looks like you started with Elixir code... nice!! I'm feeling stupid :\ thx for your answer