feck:profanities() function handling extended ascii characters
I use feck:profanities to identify the profanities.
this function correctly works for the normal text messages.
But, when the message has extended ascii characters though the message contains a profanity, function can't identify it.
message = inquiétez de
checking profanity = de
?DEBUG("reload_content_op ~p",[{Content, BlkAnd}]),
    
case catch feck:profanities( Content, BlkAnd ) of

debug line before calling the function prints below line,
reload_content_op  {<<"inqui\351tez de">>, <<"de">>}

No errors or exceptions occur. But function doesn't identify the profanity in the message.
I want to know how to manage this works for extended ascii characters.

Answering the question requires knowledge of feck which I am fairly certain is not part of standard Erlang distribution.
However this question may lead you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722624/how-to-convert-accented-strings-to-regular-strings-in-erlang
And then: https://medium.com/grindr-engineering/confusable-character-detection-in-erlang-98aa47abc9ab
